# LinkedIn send message to a connection

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use LinkedIn api to send message to a connection of the user but I find extreme lack of examples and lacking docs make it very hard to diagnose.

I do not want to request w_messages permission when user signs up, so I use javascript API to get a new access token with this permission and pass to server for SendMessage call only.

**On Client:**

```
 IN.init({
    onLoad: "onLoadApi",
    api_key: viewBag.clientSettings.LinkedInClientId,
    authorize: false,
    scope: "r_basicprofile r_network w_messages"
 });

 function onLoadApi() {
     if (!IN.User.isAuthorized()) {
        IN.User.authorize(sendMessage);
     }

     function sendMessage() {
          var w_message_accesstoken = IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token;
          $http.post("/MyApi/SendMessage/vBejds6Vh8", w_message_accesstoken);
     }
 }
```

**On Server:**

```
string jsonData = "{\"subject\":\"test subject\",\"body\":\"testbody\",\"recipients\":{\"values\":[{\"person\":{\"_path\":\"/people/vBejds6Vh8\"}}]}}"


var response= "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/vBejds6Vh8/mailbox"
                     .SetQueryParam("oauth2_access_token", accessTokenPassedFromClient)
                     .PostJsonAsync(jsonData);
```

**Result:**

```
{"Request to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/vBejds6Vh8/mailbox?oauth2_access_token=xxxxx failed with status code 401 (Unauthorized)."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to make this call as a POST call. You can only send a message on behalf of a member whose access token you have with the "w_messages" member permission.

A sample request of the POST should be: 
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox?oauth2_access_token=***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mailbox-item>
    <recipients>
        <recipient>
            <person path='/people/~' />
        </recipient>
        <recipient>
            <person path="/people/{id}" />
        </recipient>
    </recipients>
    <subject>Congratulations on your new position.</subject>
    <body>You're certainly the best person for the job!</body>
</mailbox-item>
```

Comment: In your updated example you are making the call to POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/vBejds6Vh8/mailbox. Is "vBejds6Vh8" the user whose access token you are using? Try instead using a "~". 
Also, did you get your access token via the JS API? If so you will have to exchange it for a REST token: https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

Comment: Thanks. vBejds6Vh8 is a mutual connection of the user whose access token I'm using, this is allowed right? Also, I have not implemented this exchange flow, so that is probably the issue. Will that exchange flow still work if I'm using oAuth2, because the link only mentions oAuth 1.0a. Also, step 3 states: "The easiest way to accomplish this is by using an off-the-shelf OAuth library".. I've looked around but I'm not able to find an example of such in C#. I'm using Asp.Net Identity Framework, but I'm not aware of any built in functionality for this task?

Comment: If you have an access token for user A, you should be making the POST call to user A's mailbox using the "~" to designate so, and then setting user B as a recipient.

Comment: thanks, I will try this but success would still depend on exchange JSAPI token for rest token, so would you please reply to my other questions?

Comment: Yes, you will need to exchange the JSAPI token for an oAuth 1.0 token to make the call serverside. We do not have a way to exchange the token so you can make an oAuth 2 call server side.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that W_Messages is no longer publicly available. You need to register for linkedin partnership status.